# search input by filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I made a search input by using filter method but there is a warning with this. What was wrong?

Code picture

[image: 1]

Comment: Please add the exact error. Also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your Function provided for the `Array.prototype.filter()` Method should return a boolean value to if the checked element should be kept or be filtered.
There are 2 problems with your Function: 1) it can reach a state, where no boolean value is returned. Just add `return false;` at the end. 2) You are returning the element although it only wants boolean values. Therefore the function could behave not as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have cases in which you don't return anything.

```
if (conditionA){
    return ...;
} else if (confitionB) {
    return ...;
}
// Nothing gets returned
```

You should add a return at the end of your function for when `coditionA` and `coditionB` are both `false`